# Sort within a group in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, group-by

I am using Entity Framework 6 and want to group some data with `GROUP BY`. I have to sort both the groups AND the data within a group. To make things as easy as possible I wrote a minimalistic example.

Let's assume we have some articles with a `Created-Field (only Date)`. I want to group all articles that are written on one day. And I want to group the articles itself within a group by the `Created-Field`.

This was my approach:

```
var articleGroups = DBContext.Articles
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Created)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
;
```

The groups are ordered perfectly but the ordering of the group itself is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not saying this is the solution, but have you tried grouping and sorting in memory, instead of in the database? (that is, add a `ToList()` before the `GroupBy()`), does it work?

Comment: I already tried this and it works. Sorting in memory works perfectly but it is not a solution for me as my application should be scalable. The number of records in my application is not small at all.

Comment: Btw, if this were Linq to Objects, your initial approach of sorting first would be perfectly acceptable: `The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.` ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx)) In Linq to Entity, this behavior is not guaranteed, but depends on the provider.

Comment: tell me your thoughts about my answer, please

Comment: Can you add to your sql table computing column that return date part of datetime?

Comment: I don't use a computed column in the database. Instead I am using DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime) from the Namespace System.Data.Entity. The method TruncateTime is mapped to SQL and therefore executed on database. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the responses. It seems that I just found a solution to my own problem ;)

```
var articleGroups = DBContext.Articles
    .GroupBy(x => x.Created)
    .Select(x => new {
        Created = x.Key,
        Items = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Created)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var articleGroups = DBContext.Articles
    .GroupBy(x => x.Created, 
             (x, g) => new{Key=x, Group = g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Created)})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
```

This example use signature of GroupBy with element and result selector to leverage on objects in group.

Comment: Unfortunately this doens't work. 'g' has no method OrderByDescending. Have you tested your code?

Comment: I update answer. Writing code without IDE is not easy :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
List<Articles> list = new List<Articles>() 
{
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2015, 1, 18), Smth="aa1"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2015, 1, 18), Smth="aa2"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2014, 1, 18), Smth="aa3"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2014, 1, 18), Smth="aa4"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2016, 1, 18), Smth="aa5"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2016, 1, 18), Smth="aa6"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2012, 1, 18), Smth="aa7"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2012, 1, 18), Smth="aa8"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2018, 1, 18), Smth="aa9"},
   new Articles(){DateCreated=new DateTime(2018, 1, 18), Smth="aa10"},
};
var yourQuery = (from p in list group p.DateCreated by p.DateCreated into g select new { ByDate = g.Key, GroupedColl=g.ToList() }).OrderBy(x=>x.ByDate);
```

Article Class:

```
class Articles 
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Smth { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ByDate` and `GroupedColl` are your data fields.

Comment: What's 'Cars' in this context? Where do you sort the group itself?